# Sharepoint Web Services Authentication using HttpModules

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, httpmodule

Our goal is to create SSO between non-microsoft application and Sharepoint web services, using the user & domain name (we will not have the password).
The user name will be passed through the request header to Sharepoint. I have created a HTTP Module on Sharepoint IIS site and created WindowsIdentity object based on the user available in request header. I have configured the Sharepoint 2010 IIS site for using Kerberos.I have kept the below code in AuthenticateRequest event of the HTTPModule:

`WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity("user@domain");app.Context.User = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);`

I'm getting the error as "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." in the HTTP Module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can You create an account to log in with it? As far as I know, sharepoint web services requires something like this: myservice.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: myservice.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials will work from a c# application. I didn't find a equivalent for this in non-microsoft application (ruby on rails application).

Comment: You could use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) That would work!

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. But I have to impersonate the user at the HTTPModule level. I have tried using the below code as well, but not working: WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity("user@domain"); identity.impersonate(); appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, Deepak, to hear that, try PrincipalPermission permCheck = new PrincipalPermission(null, @"DomainName\WindowsGroup");
    permCheck.Demand(); may be that do the magic trick!

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.. When I'm trying with identity.impersonate(), I'm getting the 401 error (got it when I use Fiddler tool, and from sharepoint I'm getting the credentials prompt). How do this PrincipalPermission class work in this case?

Comment: Deepak, may be we are letting the basics: does your web.config allows [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) -some like this chunk: <identity impersonate="true" />-? I'm checking out the PrincipalPermission class documentation.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, Yes impersonation is enabled.